# ADB is connected but running 'flutter devices' does not show any device

Tags: android, flutter, visual-studio-code, adb, vscode-debugger

[adb connected successfully](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uI2Ag.png)
I've connected my phone via usb or adb (I use adb from https://adb.clockworkmod.com/), both were successful (I also turned on developer mode and debug ). However, I type "flutter devices" it didn't show my device.

[download sdkmanager successfully](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDM9I.png)
When I download sdkmanager successfully, "flutter devices" shown my device. Then I run my app and get this error. Please help me!

Comment: Please do not post terminal output as screenshot. It is just so text so treat it so and just copy it into your question.

Comment: I would recommend to totally uninstall that clockwork thing. For development you should use the version that comes with flutter and Android SDK. Multiple adb versions installed only make problems. make sure you have only one `adb.exe` installed.